# How to produce proper json error response for php fatal error in Laravel 8+

Tags: laravel-8

I need to produce some proper custom error response in json format when I receive php fatal error instead of standard 500 in Laravel 8+.

How can I achieve the this outcome.
[image: Console output]

Answer (score -1):

You can use Exception. Read [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)